# If a Button is clicked the next item in a ListView is selected. How to do that?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button, selection

I have two Buttons, `Next` and `Previous`.
When the `Next` Button is pressed, the next item in a ListView should be selected.
The `Previous` Button should works just like the `Next` Button but backwards: the previous items should be selected.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedIndices < listView1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        listView1.SelectedIndices = listView1.SelectedIndices + 1;
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly add an element to the `SelectedIndices` collection: it's read-only.
You can instead set `[ListViewItem].Selected = true`: the Item will be added to the collection.

We then just verify whether the next or previous Item index falls inside the ListView Items collection bounds and select/unselect it.

I've added `ListView.Items[X].EnsureVisible()` so the list is scrolled up and down when an Item is selected/unselected.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.Items.Count == 0) return;
    int currentItem = listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0 
                    ? -1 
                    : listView1.SelectedItems[listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index;
    if (currentItem < listView1.Items.Count - 1) {
        listView1.Items[currentItem + 1].Selected = true;
        listView1.Items[currentItem + 1].EnsureVisible();
    }
    listView1.Focus();
}
```

With this method, the `Previous` Button selects backwards:

```
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.Items.Count == 0) return;
    int currentItem = listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0
                    ? -1
                    : listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
    if (currentItem > 0)
    {
        listView1.Items[currentItem - 1].Selected = true;
        listView1.Items[currentItem - 1].EnsureVisible();
    }
    listView1.Focus();
}
```

With this other method, the `Previous` Button acts as an un-selector:

```
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.Items.Count > 0 && listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
        int currentItem = listView1.SelectedItems[listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index;
        listView1.Items[currentItem].Selected = false;
        listView1.Items[currentItem].EnsureVisible();
    }
    listView1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: The next button worked perfectly ! Thank you very much. The previous button... not so good. It deselected the selected item. I wanted the the previous item to be selected. But still Thank you very much ! :D

Comment: Do you mean, you'ld like to keep one item selected? The last one? Or you want the Previous Button to just select items, let's say, backwards? I intended it as an un-selector (of sort).

Comment: Correct, I wanted the previous button to select one item backward. Just like the next Button but backward. The opposite of the next button

Comment: Thank you very much ! I appriciate it ! I don't what else I could say :D